# How to correctly nandwrite a nanddump'ed dump with oob?

Tags: linux, embedded

I am struggling on flashing a previous ROM dump of an embedded device in Linux. My previous dump contains oob data. I wrote it with `nandwrite -n -N -o /dev/mtd0 backup.bin`, and then take a ROM dump again.

By comparing the old and new ROM dump, I see some un-explainable situation: the last 24 bytes of the oob (ecc bytes) of any empty blocks (filled with 0xFF) is ought to be 0xFF also, but those in the new ROM dump is filled with 0x00, causing later write failures.

oob ought to be:

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
```

but for `nandwrite`:

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Anyone has any idea why?

---

I added a hack in the `nandwrite` code, to skip writing to NAND if the content to be written is `0xFF`, and it worked. So the problem exists when trying to write an empty page to the NAND?

---

**ADDED:**

Now I am having this problem also when writing a bootloader image. The image isn't page-aligned so `nandwrite` padded it with `0xFF`. But for pages with only `0xFF` the ecc bytes are still polluted by `0x00` just like above. Seems that my hack doesn't totally solve my problem. Anyone can help? Perhaps it could be a bug in kernel 2.6.35?

This is my hack:

```
int i;
int needwrite=0;
for (i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i){
    if(((uint8_t*)data)[i]!=0xff){
        needwrite=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(!needwrite)
    return 0;
```

Comment: What is the question here?  How to `nanddump` on my bizarre hardware?  The people are right to tell you not to ignore the OOB data.  Can we close this question as it is too localized?  As it is now, this sound like a comment on how to hack-up `nanddump` for some specific hardware's purpose.  Can you fix up the question to make it more relevant for more people?  I am using `nanddump -qobf file /dev/mtdXXX` and `nandwrite -p /dev/mtdXXX file` and want to know if I am wrong.  Google showed me this question.

Comment: @artlessnoise Feel free to vote to close if you think so. Different versions of `nanddump` has *different* functionality (as well as command line arguments) so I don't think this question can be applied generally. Check the help page of *your* version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My **hack** is adding a check in `nandwrite`, that if the whole page going to be written is totally empty (i.e. full of `0xFF`), the program will *skip* writing it (as a `flash_erase` had been done).

An extra *benefit* is that the whole process of `nandwrite` got faster because of skipping empty pages. Horray!

---

**ADDED:**

It turned out that my hack didn't actually solve the problem...

---

**ADDED again: *(real solution)***

The problem is in fact the PXA310 fills the hardware ECC bits with `0x00` for a blank page, so if the software writes an empty page, the bits gets `0x00`. This is strange, because I should have already disabled ECC in the arguments of `nandwrite`. Luckily skipping writing empty pages works in preventing problems with re-writing a ROM dump.

More information can be found in [my blog post](https://sourceforge.net/p/ipaq214android/blog/2012/10/the-strange-hardware-ecc-of-the-pxa310-flash-controller/).

A [patch sent to the linux-mtd list actually mentioned about the fact](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2011-June/035911.html).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Alvin, but the backup really will not "only work on that particular flash", because you cannot know *when* a particular bit will go from good to marginal or marginal to bad.  You may read it in one state, attempt to write it in the exact same state and fail, on any given day, with any given backup.

The *ONLY* way to safely backup the data in a NAND device is WITH ECC TURNED ON.  You read from the device with ECC corrections to get good data.  You then write the known-good data back to NAND with ECC turned on so that any bits which are now marginal or bad from when you read it before can be corrected using the NEW ECC values.

Comment: Well, the previous person who ported Linux to my device says the XIP bootloader of Windows Mobile uses the oob data *also*, so I am not sure whether I can write with ECC on and have Windows Mobile booting again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is a *warning* to you.
It *will not* work reliably.

Consider a situation where you have a block (1) with an error in position 0.
The "controller" of the Nand-flash device puts error correcting code to correct this error.

You copy the data from block 1 *with* the ECC
BUT when you write the data to a *new* Nand-flash device, you are cloning the data.
If that new nand-flash device has an error in position 1.
Then the data you write back *will be wrong* on the following read, because position 1 is bad.
But the system will think it is right, because the ECC does not show an error in position 1

You cannot reliably clone 1 nand-flash to another directly, because the hard/soft error positions are not identical.

The *only* way to do it reliably is to read the data out, use the systems ECC algorithms to correct any errors.
Write the data out to a new device, use the systems algorithms to correct any bit errors.

You may think the devices are the same, but the results are data/program corruption due to mismatches in the bit error maps.

In response to Alvin's comment:

> I am quite confident that I am cloning the exact same NAND, i.e. I made a backup of that particular chip and then write it back to THAT particular chip. It's not me who think it's the same, but there is only one single chip from the beginning to the end. It is quite strange but some other people state that it worked on their own device, while mine doesn't, could there be a bug in the driver? – Alvin Wong Aug 5 at 5:16

Sorry *not* possible (unless you are really..really..really lucky and get chips with 0 defects)

Each Nand-Flash chip has its own set of defect bits, they are Unique. 
The way that a user gets round it, is to generate a file system that masks out the bad blocks once the bad bits gets beyond the capability of the CRC.
 When you copy a nand-chip to another device, the CRC map matches the master chip. when you do a 1:1 clone of the device, some of the data bits will flip after the write (bad cells) and since you are doing a clone, you do not take into account in the CRC that these bits have flipped (because you are doing a verbatim copy).

The fact that it "works" for some people, does not mean it is correct, any more than I can drive a car, but I only find the brakes don't work when I need them. Even worse is the fact that many of these so called 'experts' on the net actually erase the defect map supplied by the manufacturer when they "clone" the device" or  perform a "chip erase" *before* saving the defect map.

This is what happens with many of the 'dodgy' nand-flash usb sticks coming out of ebay, they are actually chips with the "defect map" erased , as a result they look like good devices, until you try to save content to them.

Comment: I am quite confident that I am cloning the exact same NAND, i.e. I made a backup of that particular chip and then write it back to **THAT** particular chip. It's not me who think it's the same, but there is only one single chip from the beginning to the end. It is quite strange but some other people state that it worked on their own device, while mine doesn't, could there be a bug in the driver?

Answer (score 0):

In my embedded world, you'd first use `flash_erase` to blast everything followed by `nandwrite -p` to pad the rest of the page beyond your data with 0xFF.

```
Usage: nandwrite [OPTION] MTD_DEVICE [INPUTFILE|-]
Writes to the specified MTD device.

  -m, --markbad           Mark blocks bad if write fails
  -N, --noskipbad         Write without bad block skipping
  -o, --oob               Image contains oob data
  -O, --onlyoob           Image contains oob data and only write the oob part
  -r, --raw               Image contains the raw oob data dumped by nanddump
  -s addr, --start=addr   Set start address (default is 0)
  -p, --pad               Pad to page size
  -b, --blockalign=1|2|4  Set multiple of eraseblocks to align to
  -q, --quiet             Don't display progress messages
      --help              Display this help and exit
      --version           Output version information and exit
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. The image is a raw dump which is anyway **guaranteed** to be page-padded. Besides, my problem is specific to my platform (the evil ECC which writes `0x00` to empty pages)

Comment: I'm not sure you want to write the literal raw dump back, though. I'd think you want to generate an error-corrected, bad-block removed string (e.g. "ABC123") from your dump, and then write "ABC123" back via `nandwrite`, allowing `nandwrite` to add error-correction, skip bad blocks, and add padding as necessary. Flash cells can die at any time, so the raw form of string "ABC123" might be encoded differently the second time.

Comment: No, I dump and write with no bad block skipped to ensure a 100% restored backup. I know that the backup will only work on that particular flash and that is exactly what I want.